# i want to pass the selected value from react-bootstrap drop down component . i have no idea to pass the value to a function

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, react-bootstrap

this is my function where i have to pass the drop down selected value.

```
function getsign(sign){

}
```

this is my react-bootstrap dropdown component i want to pass the selected value to the function .

```
<DropdownButton id="dropdown-item-button" title="Your  Sign"  onSelect={getsign(value)} >
  <Dropdown.Item as="option" value={'option1'}>Option 1</Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item as="option" value={'option2'}>Option 2</Dropdown.Item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the e.target.value from the dropdown button. Hope from this console you will get the value from dropdowns

```
<DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Dropdown button" onSelect={(event,e)=>this.getsign(event,e.target.value)}>
    <Dropdown.Item as="option" value='option1'>Option 1</Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item as="option" value='option2'>Option 2</Dropdown.Item>
 
</DropdownButton>
    
 function getsign(events,value){
  console.log('value :', value);
  console.log('events :', events);

  }
```